# Как отменить выполнение popstate до клика по стрелкам "назад", "вперед"

Tags: html5-history-api

В момент загрузки страницы срабатывается следующий код

```
 window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    бла-бла-бла
    });
```

Как сделать, чтобы код срабатывал тока после клика по стрелкам "назад" и "вперед"

Comment: я делал это так: https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API/blob/master/history.js#L766-L781

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
        // тут аякс
    }, false);
}, 0);`

Comment: а как эта функция запустится? не пойму. сорри за глупый вопрос

Comment: При первом запуске сайта алерт выскакивает

setTimeout(function() {

    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
        alert()
    }, false);

}, 0);

Comment: Сработает таймаут, запустит метод навешивания события. Далее при нажатии назад/вперед будет срабатывать метод висящий на событии popstate.

Comment: Алерт срабатывает при открытии сайта сходу

Comment: Оберните это все в событие `onload`

Comment: Не помогло или я некорректно написал код
    window.onload = setTimeout(function() {

         window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
             alert()
         }, false);

     }, 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
            alert('ok');
        }, false);
    }, 0);
}, false);
```

Comment: Воо! Вот это другое дело ) Спасибо!